# Convert time string expressed as "3.5 days" to " 3.5*24 hours" in Python

Tags: python-3.x

Here is my array:

```
           ['','','','','2,509','2.58 hrs / 1.20 days','38','7.78 
           hrs / 1.16 days','1.28','6.62 mins / 6.62 mins']
```

i want to convert all days,mins to hrs, how should i do it?

like       ['','','','','2,509','2.58 hrs / 28.8 hrs','38','7.78 
               hrs / 27.84 hrs','1.28','0.110 hrs / 0.110 hrs']

Comment: how do you know which is which? eg what is 2,509? is it days hours mins? and what does `2.58 hrs / 1.20 days` mean?

Comment: if there is no unit, just keep it is. The only thing i want to convert is the number who contains "days" and "mins" to hours.@Onyambu

Comment: i am sorry, can i revise my question that i want the results looks like: ['','','','','2,509','2.58 hrs / 28.8 hrs','38','7.78 hrs / 27.84 hrs','1.28','0.110 hrs / 0.110 hrs'], the days actually converts to hours. @Onyambu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import re

a =  ['','','','','2,509','2.58 hrs / 1.20 days','38','7.78 hrs / 1.16 days','1.28','6.62 mins / 6.62 mins']

def repl(x):
   n ={'days':'*24hrs','mins': '/60 hrs'}.get(x.group(2))
   n = '' if n is None else n
   s = '' if x.group(2) in['mins','days'] else 'hrs'
   return x.group(1)+s+n

re.sub(r'(\d\S+)\s([a-z]+)',repl,"\n".join(a)).split('\n')
['',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '2,509',
 '2.58hrs / 1.20*24hrs',
 '38',
 '7.78hrs / 1.16*24hrs',
 '1.28',
 '6.62/60 hrs / 6.62/60 hrs']
```

Although this is a replicate of your solution, It will not make quite sense as to whether to divide first or multiply first etc.. So I guess introduction of parenthesis will be great:

```
def repl(x):
   n ={'days':'*24 hrs','mins': '/60 hrs'}.get(x.group(2))
   n = '' if n is None else n
   if x.group(2)=='hrs': return x.group(1)+x.group(2) + n
   return f'({x.group(1)} {n})'       


re.sub(r'(\d\S+)\s([a-z]+)',repl,"\n".join(a)).split('\n')
Out[1211]: 
['',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '2,509',
 '2.58hrs / (1.20*24 hrs)',
 '38',
 '7.78hrs / (1.16*24 hrs)',
 '1.28',
 '(6.62/60 hrs) / (6.62/60 hrs)']
```

if you needed to solve:

```
a =  ['','','','','2,509','2.58 hrs / 1.20 days','38','7.78 hrs / 1.16 days','1.28','6.62 mins / 6.62 mins']

def repl(x):
   n ={'days':'*24','mins': '/60'}.get(x.group(2))
   n = '' if n is None else n
   s = '' if x.group(2) in['mins','days'] else 'hrs'
   return str(round(eval(re.sub('[^0-9.]','',x.group(1))+n),4))+'hrs'

 re.sub(r'(\d\S+)\s([a-z]+)',repl,"\n".join(a)).split('\n')
['',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '2,509',
 '2.58hrs / 28.8hrs',
 '38',
 '7.78hrs / 27.84hrs',
 '1.28',
 '0.1103hrs / 0.1103hrs']
```

Comment: i am sorry, can i revise my question that i want the results looks like: ['','','','','2,509','2.58 hrs / 28.8 hrs','38','7.78 hrs / 27.84 hrs','1.28','0.110 hrs / 0.110 hrs'], the days actually converts to hours. @Onyambu